# Can I separate mod in subtraction?

Tags: polynomials

So I have the following equation:
s1 - s2 = A mod C - B mod C

Can I do the following? -
s1 - s2 = (A - B) mod C

Thanks

Comment: For one thing, this has nothing to do with polynomials.  For another thing, the notation "A mod C - B mod C" is (almost) never used.  mod generally only comes at the end of the statement in order to specify in terms of which equivalence relation we are working.

Answer (score 2):

No: for example, $2\bmod 5-4\bmod 5=-2$, but $(2-4)\bmod 5=-2\bmod 5=3$. What you *can* say is that

$$\big((A\bmod C)-(B\bmod C)\big)\bmod C=(A-B)\bmod C\;;$$

you need that extra $\operatorname{mod}C$ on the lefthand side.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed!!

Comment: @Sanket: You’re welcome!